# How to Customize the google sign In button?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to customise the Google sign in button according to my design.

**Image is attached**

[image]

Comment: you can make any button as Google sign in button

Comment: Create FrameLayout, put your `Button` below default google sign in button

Comment: similarly can we use any button for facebook as well @jagapathi

Comment: yes we can @SunilP

Comment: If we use any button for facebook as well, will we get registerCallback method.? @jagapathi

Comment: yes you can read the docs how it works

Answer (score 1):

Make any button in your UI and call this function on button click.

```
public void gPlusSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(YourActivity.this)
        .enableAutoManage(YourActivity.this /* Activity */
                , this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Google will provide you login response in onActivityResult method :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                //get user's email
                String mEmail = acct.getEmail();

                //get user's full name
                String mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();

                String gPlusID = acct.getId();
            }
    }
}
```